# php require($file) : failed to open stream

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I am writing code with yii2 advance.

> Warning: require($file): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Yii-Dummy\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>   Fatal error: require():  Failed opening required '$file'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Yii-Dummy\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line
>   66.

This problem is showing me. Please say me what can i do.

Comment: Correct your path

Comment: how to correct my path.. please help me.

Comment: What does it say on line 66 of autoload_real.php? Looks like the `$file` variable did not get expanded. Your best bet is running `composer` before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

seem your code pass `C:\xampp\php\PEAR` path as a file to `required`, check your code and resolve it!
it must be a file path not a folder path, and if you passed file path; check passed file is exist or not.

Comment: Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Yii-Dummy\frontend\web/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Yii-Dummy\frontend\web\index.php on line 6

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Yii-Dummy\frontend\web/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Yii-Dummy\frontend\web\index.php on line 6